Embed digital signature(pkcs7) to pdf
I am implementing signing of a PDF. I have pkcs7 value and I want to embed it in the PDF.
I am using pdf-lib and node-signpdf
The PDF file is getting signed, but when verifying using pdfsign, I am getting this error:
pdfsig signed.pdf
Digital Signature Info of: signed.pdf
Syntax Error (0): Illegal values in ByteRange array
Signature #1:
  - Signer Certificate Common Name: (null)
  - Signer full Distinguished Name: (null)
  - Signing Time: Jun 24 2024 19:49:21
  - Signing Hash Algorithm: unknown
  - Signature Type: adbe.pkcs7.detached
  - Signed Ranges: [0 - 99393], [99403 - 116849]
  - Not total document signed
  - Signature Validation: Signature has not yet been verified.

This is my code:
const fs = require('fs');
const { PDFDocument, PDFName, PDFHexString, PDFArray, PDFDict, PDFNumber } = require('pdf-lib');
const { plainAddPlaceholder } = require('node-signpdf/dist/helpers');

async function embedSignatureToPdf(pdfPath, outputPdfPath, base64Signature) {
    try {
        // Read the PDF
        const pdfBuffer = fs.readFileSync(pdfPath);

        // Add a placeholder for the signature
        const pdfWithPlaceholder = plainAddPlaceholder({
            pdfBuffer,
            reason: 'I am the author',
            contactInfo: 'contact@example.com',
            name: 'Author',
            location: 'Location',
        });

        // Debugging: Log the length of the PDF with placeholder
        console.log('pdfWithPlaceholder length:', pdfWithPlaceholder.length);

        // Convert Base64 signature to Buffer
        const pkcs7Buffer = Buffer.from(base64Signature, 'base64');

        // Find the ByteRange placeholder position
        const byteRangePlaceholder = '**********';
        const byteRangePos = pdfWithPlaceholder.indexOf(byteRangePlaceholder);
        if (byteRangePos === -1) {
            throw new Error('Could not find ByteRange placeholder in the PDF');
        }

        // Calculate the lengths of the first and second ranges
        const length1 = byteRangePos;
        const length2 = pdfWithPlaceholder.length - (length1 + byteRangePlaceholder.length);

        // Calculate ByteRange values
        const byteRange = [
            0, // start1
            length1, // length1
            length1 + byteRangePlaceholder.length, // start2
            length2, // length2
        ];

        // Ensure the ByteRange values are correct
        console.log('ByteRange:', byteRange);
        const totalSignedLength = length1 + length2;
        console.log('totalSignedLength:', totalSignedLength);
        if (totalSignedLength !== pdfWithPlaceholder.length - byteRangePlaceholder.length) {
            throw new Error('ByteRange values do not sum up to the total document length minus the placeholder length');
        }

        // Format ByteRange values as a string
        const byteRangeStr = byteRange.map(val => `0000000000${val}`.slice(-10)).join(' ');

        // Debugging: Log ByteRange string
        console.log('ByteRangeStr:', byteRangeStr);

        // Replace ByteRange placeholder with actual values
        let pdfWithByteRange = Buffer.concat([
            pdfWithPlaceholder.slice(0, byteRangePos),
            Buffer.from(byteRangeStr),
            pdfWithPlaceholder.slice(byteRangePos + byteRangePlaceholder.length),
        ]);

        // Load the PDF document with ByteRange replaced
        const signedPdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(pdfWithByteRange);

        // Get the AcroForm dictionary
        const acroForm = signedPdfDoc.context.lookup(signedPdfDoc.catalog.get(PDFName.of('AcroForm')));
        if (!acroForm) {
            throw new Error('Could not find AcroForm in the PDF');
        }

        // Get the signature field
        const fields = acroForm.lookup(PDFName.of('Fields'), PDFArray);
        const signatureField = fields.lookup(0, PDFDict);
        const signatureDict = signatureField.lookup(PDFName.of('V'), PDFDict);

        // Set the /ByteRange entry with the calculated ByteRange
        const byteRangeArray = PDFArray.withContext(signedPdfDoc.context);
        byteRange.forEach(val => byteRangeArray.push(PDFNumber.of(val)));
        signatureDict.set(PDFName.of('ByteRange'), byteRangeArray);

        // Set the /Contents entry with the PKCS#7 signature
        const hexSignature = PDFHexString.of(pkcs7Buffer.toString('hex'));

        // Ensure the contents fit in the allocated space
        const placeholderLengthBytes = byteRangePlaceholder.length * 2; // Each byte is represented by 2 hex digits
        const paddedSignature = hexSignature.value.padEnd(placeholderLengthBytes, '0');

        signatureDict.set(PDFName.of('Contents'), PDFHexString.of(paddedSignature));

        // Save the signed PDF
        const signedPdfBytes = await signedPdfDoc.save();
        fs.writeFileSync(outputPdfPath, signedPdfBytes);

        console.log('PDF signed successfully!');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error signing PDF:', error);
    }
}


using https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-lib?activeTab=dependents
